# converting t-sql to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I wrote the followig t-sql script
i want to run it in mysql.

but get syntax error on

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '[dbo].[Attachment_Attachment](    [AttachmentId]
>   [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,  [' at line 3 */ /* 0 rows affected, 0
>   rows found. Duration for 0 of 1 query: 0.000 sec. */

How can i fix this?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Attachment_Attachment](
    [AttachmentId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [AttachmentTypeId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [IconUrl] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ArrivalTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DYNAMIC_TYPE] [nchar](200) NULL,
    [LocationId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__Metadata__3214EC0717F790F9] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AttachmentId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Attachment_Attachment]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Metadata_Attachment_Metadata_AttachmentType] FOREIGN KEY([AttachmentTypeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Attachment_AttachmentType] ([TypeId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Attachment_Attachment] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Metadata_Attachment_Metadata_AttachmentType]
GO
```

Comment: Obviously T-SQL works only in SQL Server, so you just cannot use it as-is

Comment: what equivalent to guid?

Comment: T-SQL and MySQL use significantly different syntax.  You are going to have to find reference documentation for both (Google is your friend), understand what the T-SQL is doing, and then rewrite the query in MySQL.  There are no shortcuts.

Comment: Break it down.  Start with a basic table with no constraints or relationships.  Maybe start with error message.  Did you vote HLGEM down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd give something along these lines a try, though a lot of what you specify there has no direct translation

```
CREATE TABLE `dbo`.`Attachment_Attachment`(
    `AttachmentId` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `UserId` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `AttachmentTypeId` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `IsDeleted` `bit` NOT NULL,
    `Name` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    `IconUrl` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    `ArrivalTime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `DYNAMIC_TYPE` CHAR(200) NULL,
    `LocationId` VARCHAR(36) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`AttachmentId`),
    INDEX `FK_Metadata_Attachment_Metadata_AttachmentType` (`AttachmentTypeId`)
)
```

Whether you wish to have a couple more indexes i.e. on UserId is up to you